# Azure DevOps Server - Who changed a specific field via history

Tags: analytics, azure-devops-server-2019

I am working on a analytics query in Azure DevOps Server 2019 that will be set up as a data feed into PowerBI Desktop. I need to know who updated a new custom field on a work item, which may or may not be the last change made, and what that update is. I've tried using the following:

- ChangedBy *Works only if the last change is the one needed*
- History Contains [*field name*] *doesn't work at all*

Is there a way to query for a specific history entry that captures the update of a field and who made it in DevOps Server, or will it have to be written using the API?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to try out below rest api. How did it go?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking.  I'm struggling a bit as I'm a BA, not a dev, so I'm trying to learn enough about REST API's and how to correctly write an Advanced Editor query to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get the historical updates of a workitem. Below rest api will get the detailed information of all the updates of a workitem:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/updates?api-version=5.0
```

You can call above rest api in PowerBI query to get the updates historical data. For example example:

In the PowerBI Desktop go to **Get Data-**>**Blank Query**->**Advanced Editor** :

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/369/updates?api-version=5.0")),
    value = Source[value]
in
    value
```

To get the changed data of a specific historical update, you can use get update rest api:

You will to call the first rest api to list all the updateNumbers and use below:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/updates/{updateNumber}?api-version=5.0
```

See [this blog](https://www.teamfoundation.co.za/2018/10/11/tfs-reporting-using-power-bi-and-rest-services/) for more information.

You can also get data source from the sql server of your azure devops server and query the historical update using sql. Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/work-item-history-tables?view=azure-devops-2019) for more information.

Comment: This was helpful -- thanks for the code